# Selection sort using python3

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, sorting, selection-sort

```
def selection_sort(li):
    new_list = []
    a = li[0]
    for x in range(1, len(li)):
        if li[x] < a:
            a = li[x]
            new_list = a
    print(new_list)


b = [1, 2, 5, 3, 7, 4]
selection_sort(b)
```

Why does the above code returns empty list.
Thank you

Comment: Seems your sorting logic is incorrect and you pass first value `1`. `1` is the minimum element that's why nothing append to your list

Comment: Your function doesn't include a return statement. Its outcome is None, not an empty list.

Comment: @toRex what change in code would make it to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Learn what is selection sort using [visualization](https://visualgo.net/bn/sorting). Do follow the steps how to use selection [sort](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/selection-sort/)

```
def selection_sort(li):

    for i in range(len(li)): 
        min_idx = i 
        for j in range(i+1, len(li)): 
            if li[min_idx] > li[j]: 
                min_idx = j         
        li[i], li[min_idx] = li[min_idx], li[i]
            
    print(li)

b = [1, 2, 5, 3, 7, 4]
selection_sort(b)
```

Now, from your code perspective, your `selection sort` algorithm isn't correct. Furthermore, you don't need to initialize another list to store sort element rather your function parameter `list` is kind enough to store the sort element.

Comment: Nice link too, the visualizations really help understanding.